# How to use propositional logic on a list of values in sml

Tags: sml

I am trying to use propositional logic on a list of values. I will have a list of true or false values. I have a logical expression and I am trying to apply it to a list of values. For example, the logical expression T ^ F v T ^ T will be applied to a list of values(true and false).I will be substituting my values with the T and F in the logical expression.  So a list of [true ,true ,false , false] when the expression is applied to it will be like "true ^ true v false ^ false". I will have different combination of the list of values.

```
fun take(a::b::c::d::rest) =
 (a andalso b) orelse (c andalso not d);
 
(*Test *)
take([false , false , true, false]);
val it = true : bool
```

The function works but I am wondering if I can use recursion instead to apply the logical expression to the list.

Comment: Yes, you can use recursion.

Comment: You can, but it gets convoluted and unclear, so what would be the point? (And if you always have four values, a tuple would probably be a better choice than a list.)